# Bellman Ford may not update distance correctly by termination?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

[image: bellman for example]

Consider the example shown in the above figure. Let's consider two orders (1) S, A, B and (2) S, B, A for traversing the graph and updating the distance d (numbers in circle are distance d):

1- start with S -> B = -2, A = 5; Then A -> D = 7; Then B -> A = -1. Algorithm terminates.

2- start with S -> B = -2, A = 5; Then B -> A = -1; Then A -> D = 3. Algorithm terminates.

In case 1, D = 7 by the time algorithm terminates (It is not updated by the time the algorithm is over). In case 2, D = -1 and it is correctly updated .

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I just figured that bellman ford has nothing to do with vertices. I was using adjacency list as the graph representation and I was mixing things up.
In other words, I used

```
for(node: graph.nodes) {
   for (adjNode: child.adj) {
       Relax(child, adjNode);
   }
}
```

Instead, I should have done

```
for (int i=0; i < graph.numberOfEdges() - 1; i++ ) {
  for(node: graph.nodes) {
    for (adjNode: child.adj) {
        Relax(child, adjNode);
    }
  }
}
```

The inner 2 loops simply mean all edges. So the first code traverse edges only once.

For those who happen to make the same mistake as I, remember that bellman ford traverses every edge v - 1 time. Don't think about it from a virtices perspective at all.